# How can I get the value of the modal defined angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to get the values updated by the user and paste it in the text area of a modal. But it's returning `undefined`. I am unable to sort out why.
Here is the code.

```
$scope.details=[];
$scope.addDetails=function() {
    $scope.details.push({
        Title: $scope.Details_Title,
        meta_chars: $scope.Details_metaChars,
        version: $scope.Details_version,
        Auth_name: $scope.Details_AuthName,
        copyRights: $scope.Details_copyRights
    });
}

$scope.genrate_HTML=function() {
    document.getElementById("createdHTML").value=$scope.details;
}
```

here is the html

```
<div ng-controller="GenrateHTML">//name of the controller
    <button  ng-click="genrate_HTML();toggleModal()" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="btnGenerateHTML">Generate HTML </button>
    <modal title="Enter Document Details" visible="showModal" >
        <!--<div ng-controller="GenrateHTML">-->
        <textarea contenteditable="true" type="text" id="createdHTML" name="HTML_content" placeholder="Title" style="margin-top:10px" class="form-control" ></textarea>
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal" style="margin-top:10px;margin-left:520px;" ng-click=" savefile()">Save</button>
    </modal>
</div>
```

`toggleModal()` displays the modal, `savefile()` save the file on local machine, they are working fine. But I am not sure why the textarea returns `undefined`. I have tried `pop()`, `value()`, it returns `undefined`.

Comment: Is there a reason you have not set ng-model on the textarea and then just use that value in your generate_HTML function?

Comment: i need to display the  values of model $scope.details wich user has updated using another function in this text area. so i thought ng-model is not required there plus i will be putting values from diffrent models on later stage.

Comment: I'm confused by what you are trying to do here... you appear to be trying to assign the value of a `<textarea>` to an array of objects?

Comment: yes i am trying to display values of the array in the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you're trying to have a field that is updated by the user, 'textarea' in your example, and be accessible by Javascript.

If this is the case, then as mentioned by Scott in as one of the comments to your question, you may find it beneficial to use Angular's 'ng-model' tag attribute to bind the HTML field to the to Angular controller.

An example of this is shown at AngularJS's documentation at the bottom of the page.(https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)

Notice that in the example they are using $scope, but you can easily use a variable inside the controller. To do this, you can use the following code as a reference:

app.js

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('getterSetterExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', [function() {
    //assuming there is a $scope.details that contains the necessary data
    this.details = $scope.details
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-ngModel-getter-setter-production</title>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-rc.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-app="getterSetterExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController as exampleCtrl">
  <form name="userForm">
    <label>Name:
      <input type="text" name="userName"
             ng-model="exampleCtrl.details"
             ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }" />
    </label>
  </form>
  <pre>user.name = {{exampleCtrl.details}}</pre>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i am sorry but user has  updated the "details" array  now i am trying to print the contents of that array in the text area .and its returning "undefined".

Comment: Please review the changes made above and see if it fits your needs.

Comment: Notice the "<pre>user.name = {{exampleCtrl.details}}</pre>" line. It should update as details is updated.

Comment: tried but not working .. i basically want the contents of "details" array being displayed in textarea . using a function in controller